# ASP.NET Core with AngularJS routing

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am having an issue getting my templates to show up on my SPA.  All scripts execute without an error and I can navigate to my HTML templates through the browser just fine, but angular cannot connect my route configuration to my application.

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('over_the_counter', [
        'ngRoute'
    ]);

    app.run(function() {
    });

    app.config(['$routeProvider',
        function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'app/landing/landing.html',
                    controller: 'LandingController',
                    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
        }
    ]);
}(window.angular));
```

If I browse to `http://localhost:55907/app/landing/landing.html`, then the page is rendered.  The HTML file is sitting in the `wwwroot` folder.

Comment: Could you provide with controller source where you make your connection? This code does nothing but initialization of angular application and routes.

Comment: @GrayFox why would you need to see the controller source?  My route provider is building my routes during the initialization.

Comment: I misunderstood you. So, if I get it right, your page isn't working on `http://localhost:55907/` url?

Comment: @GrayFox that's correct.  All of the JS files are being loaded correctly, and angular seems to start up ok (meaning, no errors in the console), but the templates or the routing is not working as expected.  If I run this app from static files, then everything works fine.

Comment: Is `<ng-view></ng-view>` present in server pages like `index.cshtml`?

Comment: @GrayFox yes, i tried it in `_Layout.cshtml` and `Index.cshtml`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add more configuration to the `appsettings.json` or just these lines of code to the `startup.cs` file :

```
DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions();
            options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
            options.DefaultFileNames.Add("Index.html");
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                await next();

                if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/Index.html";
                    await next();
                }
            })
            .UseCors("AllowAll")
            .UseDefaultFiles(options)
            .UseStaticFiles()
            .UseIdentity()
            .UseMvc();
```